# How to make matrix for points according to an expression

Tags: matlab, matrix, points

I have `n` 2-D circles represented by their radii and coordinates of centers. 
So, I have `nx3` matrix `[centers, radii]`.

I want to create `nxn` matrix `A` so that `A(i,j) = max(radii(i),radii(j))`.
I thought it's easy problem but unexpectedly stuck with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) with the built-in `@max` that takes care of the expansion onto a `n x n` array and then does the `max` finding for each pair of elements. Here's the code -

```
A = bsxfun(@max,radii,radii.')
```